# How to store mqtt subscribed data in database

Tags: java, mqtt

I am using MQTT Paho `MqttCallback` I am successfully able to subscribe and publish on my topic without any issues but, my task is to store the data in database which is getting in  `messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message)` so the data I can use it in future.

```
@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
    // code to store the message in database
     LOGGER.info("messageArrived>> " + message);
}
```

`messageArrived()` is not executing the code which is storing to database its simply executing the LOGGER that's.
Code to store the message in database is correct then also it is skipping the code.
What strategy do I need to apply so first it will store the message in database and prints the log.

> update

I am trying something similar to [this](http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-sql-database)

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: Yes i am using maven

Comment: Okay so what happens when you are pulling this in a debugger?

Comment: I am not debugging... but in between database code I wrote logger those things are also not printing in log...

Answer (score 0):

This will be because your logger/database code it throwing an exception that is getting swallowed by the paho framework.

Add a try/catch block round your Logger call.

```
@Override
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
     try {
         // code to store the message in database
         LOGGER.info("messageArrived>> " + message);
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         System.err.println(ex);
     }
}
```

Now it should print the reason for the failure to stderr

Comment: I tried this but dent work, my database code is not executing records are not inserting.. any other solution please @hardillb

Comment: It will still fail, but it should print a message to stderr about why it failed